# How to present categories on 2 pages

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I Need some help to present all the categories in 2 pages.
Right now I display them in 1 pages. My question is how can I display them in other page also?
This is the controller:

```
class ShopController extends MainController
{
    public function categories(){       
        self::$data['categories']=Categorie::all()->toArray();
        self::$data['title']=self::$data['title'].'| Shop Categories';
        return view('content.categories', self::$data);   
    }
```

if im trying to use extends and yield it from the page 'content.categories' it says that $categories is undefined.
(so it works only from content.categories)

Comment: are you trying to access categories at the layout that is extended by `content.categories`?

Comment: yes , but it tells me the the $categories is undefined

Comment: Try `return view('content.categories')->withCategories(self::$data);` !!

Comment: Why are you making the `$data` variable static? Have you tried it without making `$data` static?

Answer (score 0):

If you insist to do so, you could use this snippet inside your `content.categories` view file.

```
@extends('your-layout', ['categories' => $categories])
```

Comment: still it says  Undefined variable: categories (View: categories.blade.php)

Answer (score 0):

Change controller like below

```
class ShopController extends MainController
{

public function __construct()
{   
    // define variable in your construct  
    $this->data = array(
                       'title' => 'Your Title'
                      );
}

public function categories(){       
   $this->data['categories']=Categorie::all()->toArray();
   $this->data['title']=$this->data['title'].'| Shop Categories';
   return view('content.categories', $this->data);   
 }
```

In your view file `content/categories.blade.php`

Use `$categories` to get the datas